# Adding text to the end of numbers in a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have created lists by extracting lines from files, and I am trying to add `'.flac'` to the end of the numbers in each lines of the list.

**Example of a line:**

```
26-496-0000 IT WAS NOW MID JULY AND THE PLAGUE WHICH HAD CHIEFLY RAGED AT THE OTHER END OF THE TOWN AND AS I SAID BEFORE IN THE PARISHES OF SAINT GILES SAINT ANDREW'S HOLBORN
```

and I hope to change all the lines like this one in my list to:

```
26-496-0000.flac IT WAS NOW MID JULY AND THE PLAGUE WHICH HAD CHIEFLY RAGED AT THE OTHER END OF THE TOWN AND AS I SAID BEFORE IN THE PARISHES OF SAINT GILES SAINT ANDREW'S HOLBORN
```

Any ideas on how I can add `.flac` to the end of the numbers for each of these lines in my list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to do this

```
import re
s="26-496-0000 IT WAS NOW MID JULY AND THE PLAGUE WHICH HAD CHIEFLY RAGED AT THE OTHER END OF THE TOWN AND AS I SAID BEFORE IN THE PARISHES OF SAINT GILES SAINT ANDREW'S HOLBORN"
re.sub(r'^([\d-]+)', r'\1.flac', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# "26-496-0000.flac IT WAS NOW MID JULY AND THE PLAGUE WHICH HAD CHIEFLY RAGED AT THE OTHER END OF THE TOWN AND AS I SAID BEFORE IN THE PARISHES OF SAINT GILES SAINT ANDREW'S HOLBORN"
```